# Random shuffle not working for Range

Tags: scala

Scala version 2.10.3 running on java 7

```
import scala.util.Random
Random.shuffle(0 to 4) // works
Random.shuffle(0 until 4) // doesn't work
```

:9: error: Cannot construct a collection of type scala.collection.AbstractSeq[Int] with elements of type Int based on a collection of type scala.collection.AbstractSeq[Int].

The error message seems to really only tell me "You can't do that".  Anyone have any insight as to why?

Comment: my current work around: Random.shuffle((0 until 4).toIndexedSeq)

Comment: My guess is that it might have something to do with `0 to 4` and `0 until 4` being different classes `0 to 4

res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive with scala.collection.immutable.Range.ByOne = Range(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

0 until 4
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Range with scala.collection.immutable.Range.ByOne = Range(0, 1, 2, 3)
`

Comment: @Andrey yeah I noticed that... I looked at the type signature for shuffle:   def shuffle[T, CC[X] <: scala.TraversableOnce[X]](xs : CC[T])(implicit bf : scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[CC[T], T, CC[T]]) : CC[T] = { /* compiled code */ }.  I see that the error comes from the CanBuildFrom.class and that it can't find an implicit for the .Range.ByOne class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala is inferring the wrong type parameters to `shuffle`. You can force working ones with:

```
Random.shuffle[Int, IndexedSeq](0 until 4)
```

or broken ones with:

```
Random.shuffle[Int, AbstractSeq](0 to 4)
```

I don't know why it comes up with the wrong parameters for `Range`, as returned by `until`, but the correct ones for `Range.Inclusive`, as returned by `to`. `Range.Inclusive` directly subclasses `Range` without mixing in any traits, so it shouldn't be treated any differently. This looks like a Scala bug to me.